# Programmatically enable Visio External Data window using VSTO C#

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-addins, visio

Would appreciate help using the VSTO C# API to call to togglr the Visio External Data window on / off. Having looked at the reference it is not clear to me how to do this.

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio.Application.DoCmd(Visio.VisUICmds.visCmdDataExplorerWindow)

Comment: Thanks Paul Herber - the toggle works well now, however it sems to close the window if open.  Any thoughts on how to check whether the window is already open (basically I want to open the window is it is not open).

Comment: Figured out that you can check whether there are existing External Data records via: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.datarecordsets.count

Comment: Look at the Windows object, loop through all the Windows and check the window type - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.window.type

Answer (score 0):

It was not immediately apparent to me that the target Window object is nested, so I have included a working function.

```
    public void OpenDataWindow() {
        V.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application; // using V = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
        bool IsOpen = false;
        foreach (V.Window multiWin in app.Windows) {
            foreach (V.Window dockedWin in multiWin.Windows) {
                if (dockedWin.Caption.Contains("External Data")) { IsOpen = true; break; }
            }
        }
        if (IsOpen is false) app.DoCmd((short)V.VisUICmds.visCmdDataExplorerWindow);
    }
```